# How can I judge whether the code will run inside of the Composition or outside of the Composition in Android Studio Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The following content is from the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#4).

*Using LaunchedEffect in this case wasn't possible because we needed to trigger the call to create a coroutine in a regular callback that was outside of the Composition.*

I was told that I should use `LaunchedEffect` when the code run inside of the Composition, and I should use `rememberCoroutineScope` when the code run outside of the Composition.

The Code A and Code B are samples from the article above.

But I don't understand why `scaffoldState.drawerState.open()` will run outside of the Compositionn in Code A?  You know that `fun CraneHome()` is `@Composable`.

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun CraneHome(
    onExploreItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        modifier = Modifier.statusBarsPadding(),
        drawerContent = {
            CraneDrawer()
        }
    ) {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        CraneHomeContent(
            modifier = modifier,
            onExploreItemClicked = onExploreItemClicked,
            openDrawer = {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun LandingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onTimeout: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {      
        val currentOnTimeout by rememberUpdatedState(onTimeout)
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            delay(SplashWaitTime)
            currentOnTimeout()
        }

        Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_crane_drawer), contentDescription = null)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code A: you have a user action that `drawerState.open()` is performed on some user action (e.g. on click of the button), which means action is initiated outside of composition. In code B, the action (delay timeout) is initiated together with the composition (or inside composition).